# Adding and deleting VueJS form input

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs3

i am new to vue js, i have one "iban" entry that I want to do and when "add iban" button is clicked, first entry "delete" range should be added and when I want to delete it starts from above, I think I made a mistake. Thanks already for your help.

[image]

```
<template>
    <div class="col-12" v-for="(section, index) in sections">
        <div class="mb-1 row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label class="col-form-label" for="iban"><span><i data-feather='file-text'></i></span>IBAN NUMBER</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="iban" v-model="section.item">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-1 row" v-for="(addition, index) in section.additionals">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label class="col-form-label" for="iban"><span><i data-feather='file-text'></i></span>IBAN NUMBER</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Item" v-model="addition.item">
                <span class="float-right" style="cursor:pointer" @click="removeItem(index)">X</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success mt-5 mb-5" @click="addNewItem(index)">New Iban</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            data: {
                iban: "",
            },
            sections: [
                {
                    item: '',
                    additionals: [] 
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addNewItem(id) {
            this.sections[id].additionals.push({
                item: ''
            })
        },
        removeItem(index){
            this.sections[index].additionals.splice(index,1)
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Looking at your updated post & images, I think you are looking for the following:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      data: {
        iban: "",
      },
      sections: [{
        ibans: [{item: ""}]
      }]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addNewItem(id) {
      this.sections[id].ibans.push({item: ''});
    },
    removeItem(sectionIndex, ibanIndex) {
      this.sections[sectionIndex].ibans.splice(ibanIndex, 1);
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template>
    <div class="col-12 sections" v-for="(section, sectionIndex) in sections">
      <div class="mb-1 row" v-for="(iban, ibanIndex) in section.ibans">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <label class="col-form-label" for="iban"><span><i data-feather='file-text'></i></span>IBAN NUMBER</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Item" v-model="iban.item">
          <span v-if="section.ibans.length>1"
          class="float-right" style="cursor:pointer" @click="removeItem(sectionIndex, ibanIndex)">X</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-success mt-5 mb-5" @click="addNewItem(sectionIndex)">New Iban</button>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but the first input "delete" button is not added

Comment: hold on, let me update the answer. @SelaminkoElam

Comment: Quick question @SelaminkoElam what should be the initial state? Just a New Iban button? Also, what should happen when you click on the delete of the first input? Could you please elaborate on what do you mean by '**first entry "delete" range should be added and when I want to delete it starts from above**'?

Comment: There is the first iban or I want the original input "deletion" added.

Comment: okay, and what should happen on click of the `deletion` button next to the first input box? should all the additional inputs be removed? Can you check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d6fh0gjt/) and see if this is the output you want?

Comment: I added an image to the answer, can you check it?

Comment: I checked the image. I understood you require a delete button next to the first input box, but what should happen once you click on the delete button? Should all the additional inputs be removed? or should it just remove that first input box and keep all the additional boxes? if you elaborate better then I'll give you the solution in next few minutes.

Comment: look, there is no "delete" button when there is no addition in the first picture. but if an input is added, then "delete" button appears on both inputs, whichever one is desired to be deleted is deleted.

Comment: Gottcha.. Let me update the answer for you.

Comment: I uploaded the image as a gif, it would be more understandable. Can you check.

Comment: Yes, I understood. Just one more doubt. Do you really need to differentiate between the original and additional `IBAN` numbers? I mean you have created two variables i.e `item` & `additionals`. Would it be okay, if you get just a single array of all the entered `IBAN`s be it additional or original? I mean, if one is entered, you will get array of 1 IBAN. if two are entered you will get array of 2 IBANs.. would that be fine?

Comment: When I post the form, I intend to send it in iban json format.

Comment: @SelaminkoElam I updated my answer as per your explanation. Please check it out.

Comment: my teacher does not appear in the post process :S

Comment: do you have Skype ?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236103/vuejs-input-forms Join this for discussions

Comment: My reputation score is low, I'm a new member

Comment: https://www.chatib.us login without registration and let me know your username

Comment: username kaan0033

Comment: Salvino ? are you there

Answer (score 0):

I think this code could help you.

```html
<template>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div
      class="mb-1 row"
      v-for="(item, index) in sections.additionals"
      :key="index"
    >
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label for="iban" class="col-form-label">
          <span><i data-feather="file-text"></i></span>IBAN NUMBER
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="iban" v-model="item.item" />
        <span
          class="float-right"
          style="cursor: pointer"
          @click="removeItem(index)"
          >X</span
        >
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-success mt-5 mb-5" @click="addNewItem">
        New Iban
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      data: {
        iban: "",
      },
      sections: { additionals: [{ item: "" }] },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addNewItem() {
      this.sections.additionals.push({
        item: this.data.iban,
      });
    },
    removeItem(index) {
      this.sections.additionals.splice(index, 1);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```